# Best way to sync data from one database to another

Tags: database-design, azureservicebus

Let's say I have my web shop and database have multiple tables like Products, Product prices and similar. I'm selling my software solution to my affiliate partner. He gets its database, it window application for entering data and I want all he's products are available on my website also. So, I have my products and sell them on my website. Partner has his website and his products, but I also want that all his products are also available in my database. My initial idea was to build some kind of app that periodically connects to Partner's database and insert/update data to my tables. But recently I think about some service buses. Is service bus way to go ? So situation would be like this. Partner inserts product (bus sends message that products was inserted, partner updates prices then bus sends message that some row in prices row was changed. I would then have some console app running on server that listens to message and updates to my database. What do you think would be scalable solution? Example is fictional and in real life I have lot of tables.

Answer (score 0):

> My initial idea was to build some kind of app that periodically connects to Partner's database and insert/update data to my tables. But recently I think about some service buses. Is service bus way to go ?

In my opinion, as you mentioned, Azure Service Bus could be used as an approach for the scenario. You could let your partner create a message when he inserts/updates his database record in his program, and then you could run [background tasks/jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs) on a schedule (or continuously) to consume messages and insert/updates records in your own database. And for improved performance and availability, you could use partitioned queue(s) (or topic).

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements) describes how to use Azure Service Bus messaging to optimize performance, please refer to it. And please remember to check and process [dead-letter queue (DLQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues) in your tasks/jobs.